# Why did this route work? Using another player's station, in Ticket to Ride Online?

Tags: online, ticket-to-ride-europe

We had this situation recently in the online Ticket to Ride. Why did Yellow's route from London to Berlin work? Is Yellow really allowed to use Purple's station on Essen?

[image]

Comment: There appears to be a yellow station at München, where the green and purple wagons join up, the purple line continuing from there to Berlin. Is that normal? Could it affect the road leading to Berlin?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's hard to tell with the big green destination marker, but it looks like there is a yellow train station in Berlin, which would allow Yellow to use the track from Essen to complete the ticket.

[image: cropped screenshot showing the hidden station]

Comment: Good eye! I think you're right!

Comment: Yup, just zoomed in loads, and you're right, if you compare it to the green marker at the other end of the route, it should be clear

Comment: The online game should probably in this case highlight the train station involved just like the trains: drawn above the marker. I suggest submitting a ticket (no pun intended) to the developer suggesting that.

Comment: Also note that the purple station on Essen is *not* highlighted, indicating it is not being used as one might think when first looking at the image (I know I did). This also points to a yellow station on Berlin being used to claim purple's track.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell that should not have worked at all. It seems like the T2R online simulation has a route calculation bug. I suggest reporting this to them.

Players can only use their own train stations. [From Ticket to Ride Europe's rules](https://ncdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/te_rules_2015_en.pdf) (page 6):

> A Train Station allows its owner to use one, and only one, of the routes belonging to another player, into (or out of) that city to help him connect the cities on his Destination Tickets.

There is no allowance for players other than the owner to make use of a train station, or for the owner to share it, or anything like that. The owner gets the route and that's that.